# Find all Quarters between 2 months

Tags: php

In Indian Standards, Quarters are arranged in this fashion.

- Q1 - Apr to Jun
- Q2 - Jul to Sep
- Q2 - Oct to Dec
- Q2 - Jan to Mar

The Input that I have is 
`$StartDate='01-2014'; $EndDate='02-2015`
Where 01-2014 tells starting from First Quarter of 2014 and 02-2015 tells ends at second Quarter of 2015. I need to write a function which would return me an array with all the Quarters between these 2 dates. How would I achieve this? The array should look like this.

> $qtrArr = ['1-2014', '2-2014', '3-2014', '4-2014', '1-2015', '2-2015'];

Comment: 01-2014 starts from q4 of 2013 ?

Comment: No. Its first Quarter of 2014.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a good opportuntity to learn about some PHP's [`DateTime`](http://php.net/datetime) functionality.

One way to express your definition of a quarter is through a [`DatePeriod`](http://php.net/dateperiod), which allows you iterate over a period of time or a set of dates that are recurring at a regular interval. So yours is a perfect use case for this. Here's an example...

```
function getQuarters($start, $end) {

    $StartDate = DateTime::createFromFormat('m-Y', $start);
    $EndDate   = DateTime::createFromFormat('m-Y', $end);
    $quarters  = new DatePeriod($StartDate, new DateInterval('P3M'), $EndDate);
    $p = 0;
    $r = [];
    foreach($quarters as $quarter) {
        if (!$p) {
            $q = [$quarter];
            $p++;
        } else {
            $q[] = $quarter;
            $p = 0;
            $r[] = $q;
        }
    }
    return $r;

}

var_dump(getQuarters('01-2014','02-2015'));
```

So you get something like this...

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    object(DateTime)#8 (3) {
      ["date"]=>
      string(26) "2014-01-04 09:45:46.000000"
      ["timezone_type"]=>
      int(3)
      ["timezone"]=>
      string(16) "America/New_York"
    }
    [1]=>
    object(DateTime)#9 (3) {
      ["date"]=>
      string(26) "2014-04-04 09:45:46.000000"
      ["timezone_type"]=>
      int(3)
      ["timezone"]=>
      string(16) "America/New_York"
    }
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    object(DateTime)#10 (3) {
      ["date"]=>
      string(26) "2014-07-04 09:45:46.000000"
      ["timezone_type"]=>
      int(3)
      ["timezone"]=>
      string(16) "America/New_York"
    }
    [1]=>
    object(DateTime)#11 (3) {
      ["date"]=>
      string(26) "2014-10-04 09:45:46.000000"
      ["timezone_type"]=>
      int(3)
      ["timezone"]=>
      string(16) "America/New_York"
    }
  }
}
```

Where you basically have an array of arrays. Each element represents a quarter and each sub element represents the start and end date of that quarter.

---

Also note that this particular example doesn't conclude your exact requirements as it's exclusive rather than treating the `DatePeriod` as an adjacency list, which is more along the lines of what you're looking for. So feel free to edit it as required. This was just off the top of my head.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative if you don't want to use `DateTime`.

```
function getQuarters($start,$end){
    $start_q = (int) explode('-',$start)[0];
    $start_y = (int) explode('-',$start)[1];

    $end_q = (int) explode('-',$end)[0];
    $end_y = (int) explode('-',$end)[1];

    $r = ["$start_q-$start_y"];
    $next_q = $start_q;
    $next_y = $start_y;

    while($next_q != $end_q || $next_y != $end_y){
            $next_y = $next_q == 4 ? $next_y + 1 : $next_y;
        $next_q = $next_q == 4 ? 1 : $next_q + 1;

        $r[] = "$next_q-$next_y";
    }

    return $r;
}
```

The result of

```
$StartDate='01-2014'; 
$EndDate='02-2015';

print_r(getQuarters($StartDate,$EndDate));
```

is

```
Array ( [0] => 1-2014 [1] => 2-2014 [2] => 3-2014 [3] => 4-2014 [4] => 1-2015 [5] => 2-2015 )
```